# aws lambda using java 13

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda's currently only supports Java 8 and 11.

I want to run a method for each value inside an SQS. This method uses Java 13. I found 2 options to do that:

- Run an ec2 machine with a script to "listen" on the sqs and try to fetch messages from it. For example, in an infinite loop. Whenever it finds such message, process it and delete it from the queue. By that, I implement the sqs trigger mechanism on my own.
- The second way I found is hacky. I can write a simple python script and zip it with my Jar file and the JVM. Them, we the lambda zip would be open on the machine i will have both these files. Then, the python script will run my jar using `subprocess`.

Is there another way to work with sqs and java 13 so the method would be triggered by the sqs?

Thank you

Comment: Java 13 is already out of support.  Amazon is certainly not going to support JVM's that have a 6 month lifetime.  While I can't fathom code that won't also work on Java 11 your only choice is your own EC2 with Java 13 installed on it.

Comment: they doesn't support new versions either. I don't mind using newer version if you have a solution for that :)

Comment: All JVM's until Java 17 are going to be supported for about 6 months each.  Amazon will not be able to support any of them.  If you really require this then you'll need your own environment.  I would not run production caliber code on this environment as the non-LTS releases (i.e. anything but Java 8 and Java 11 currently) are not very well supported.  What code do you have that requires Java13?